# Synchronizing count query in JPA

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jpa

My application has jobs. Each job contains lot of tasks in different states (Task States: Initial, Running, Retry, Success, Failure). The response for each tasks some to a queue. My application has 100 consumers processing task responses from this queue (Container Managed MDBs). Each consumer processes task response xml and base of the state in the response xml changes that state of the task in DB (say from Running to Retry etc..). If the task status moves to success or failure(after all retries are exhausted), then my application must sent to upstream application a response indicating task status, total tasks in the job, the current task number(number of tasks of this job which have reached final state which is success or Failure).

I use JPA count queries to get the total tasks within a Job and current task.  My problem is with the count query to fetch current task number. Consider my Job A has tasks T1, T2 and T3. If my consumers processes the messages in parallel say both T1 and T2 are processed by two consumers in parallel, then the count query causes issues as both T1 and T2 count query returns 1 for both tasks as they seem to be processed in parallel (instead of my expected output of 1 and 2). I am not sure how to synchronize this as i do not want to end up processing tasks in a job sequentially as there can be more than 40000 tasks in a job and also the transaction is further container managed transaction. Is there a way to get the task count correct without making task processing sequential?

Comment: You could launch a task that does counting after processing task has been completed. It does add overhead though and you just might get better performance with pessimistic lock on job

Comment: @SamiKorhonen The task is processed by MDB and processing of tasks along with sending of response to task(where count query is utilized) is part of same container managed transaction. Currently I am executing the count query at the end but however since it is part of the current transaction and there is a parallel transaction processing a different task within same job which is not yet committed, the count returns incorrect result.

Comment: Yes, but the idea is to do counting in different transaction. You post a request to count in the transaction that you execute the task in, but you do the counting in a new transaction.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen the processing of tasks and sending of response for task must happen in a single transaction since if there is some error encountered i have to roll back the complete JTA transaction and put the task message back into input queue.

Comment: I guess you should use pessimistic locking: create a column on job that indicates how many tasks are still pending. Update and retrieve that column after task completes (in same transaction)